# javascript compatibility question

Tags: javascript, asp.net, compatibility

I've been trying to track down a strange bug in one of my web applications.  Here is the sequence of events:

1. user clicks on a link in the webpage
   which fires javascript that uses a
   window.showModalDialog to open a URL
2. this url is an asp.net page that
   uses a binary write to display a PDF

When I run this in Firefox it works fine.  When I run it in IE nothing displays on the page and it never errors out.

If I go directly to the url of the asp.net page in either FF or IE it works fine.  Are there any window.showModalDialog issues that could be causing this?

Code from the aspx page page load:

```
    Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("...")
    Dim resp As WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
    Dim rdr As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(resp.GetResponseStream())
    Dim pdfByte() As Byte = rdr.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(resp.ContentLength))
    Response.Clear()
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.BinaryWrite(pdfByte)
    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()
```

Javascript:

```
window.showModalDialog(sUrl,'',sFeatures)
```

The javascript i posted is where the problem occurs out.  Let me know if you need more.

Comment: Can you show us this javascript code? I am talking about this window.showModalDialog

Comment: If it works fine in Firefox then it's not a server-side bug. The code that you've posted here is server-side.

Comment: have you tried setting 
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

Comment: Just gave it a shot.  No dice.

Comment: Does writting plain old vanilla HTML back from your aspx page work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing my `window.showModalDialog` to a `window.open`.  I found a few others that had this problem but no real solution to get it working with showModalDialog.

Answer (score 0):

I remember that in IE the name of the page could cause problems, I wrote about this years ago there http://amrelgarhytech.blogspot.com/2008/06/windowopen-invalid-argument.html

But I am not sure if this is your problem

Comment: Window.open works fine.  It's window.showModalDialog that gives me trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I seems there is an issue with IE, modal dialog and PDFs:

http://technicalsol.blogspot.com/2008/06/pdf-in-modal-dialog-box.html

The work around appears to be embed the PDF in an iFrame.